# How to debug L1 Auto negotiation issues?

Tags: cisco, switch, ethernet, layer1, cisco-nexus-5k

One of our Linux hosts has started switching its gears recently. While checking the interface speed, I could see that the interface has switched down to **10Mbps**. The NIC and Switch are capable of 1G and auto negotiation is enabled at both sides. I would like to debug the root cause of the issue. We are planning to perform the below mentioned actions.

1. Perform the cable test to check/replace the Cat6 cable.
2. Double check
   on the switch configurations. (Link capability and L1
   Advertisements coming out of Switch)

Given that tcpdump works from L2 and up there is no point in getting the tcpdump . Do you guys have any other pointers? Perhaps, syslog/dmseg ?

I have already tried to capture the L1 advertisements but the command is not supported. The switch platform we are using is Cisco 5596.

We generally use the command `show controllers <interface> | include Autoneg Lnk Ptr abty` to decode the fast link pulse messages but that is not supported in the 5596 switch. We have already confirmed that both NIC (via ethtool) and switch will support 10, 100 and 1G.

How do you approach issues and collect stats on issues at L1/Phy layer (especially link speed switching down from 1G to 10M)?

[image]

Comment: A while ago, there used to be issues when one side of the link was forced to a specific speed/duplex and the other wasn't (because it would disable negotiation). Not sure if those kind of issues still exist nowadays, but you may want to check the configuration for the interface on both sides.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Likely it's the cable.

While there were some issues with the Autonegotiation standard very early on, they've been resolved for decades and anything from 2000+ can't be affected.

Generally, leave Autonegotiation enabled at all times. Most often, when you think you need to configure it manually it lands on your feet some time later.

When checking for cable or port issues it's a good idea to check the logged events and port error counters first. Frequent relinking and sub-speed linking indicate cable damage (can also be caused by poor cable quality or installation, or exceeded reach). FCS errors, runts, giants and such indicate general transmission problems.

I usually move production to another switch port (configure appropriately!) and patch cable(s) to solve the issue quickly. Then I check out the cable and test the port - 99.5% of the time it's the cable.

Generally, it's a good idea to implement some port monitoring so you'd get an early warning in case a port doesn't link as expected or accumulates errors.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.I'm taking all of your suggestions and framing an action plan.

Given that the command "show controllers <interface> | include Autoneg Lnk Ptr abty" is not working, Do you know any other alternative commands to check the L1 advertisements coming out of the NIC towards switch port?

Comment: No, sorry. Not really familiar with Nexus.

Comment: The team is not willing to replace the cable.So, I went ahead and reconfigured it to Auto negotiation and it was reproduced. I could see the following. Ethtool output showed as 10,100,1000 all modes are supported,Dmesg- A NIC down and UP event ,ethtool -S errors ( txerror- 946,collision 9782,tx_window_error 946,tx_abort_late_coll -946,tx_deferred_ok- 8813,single_coll_ok-5845 etc. When I checked with a working device,I could see there was absolute 0 of tx erros,window errors.  Does this mean that the issue is at the switch or within the  NIC of equipment itself?

Comment: The collision/late_coll counters indicate a duplex mismatch with half duplex at that end. Either the far port is manually forced to full duplex (breaking autoneg) or there really is a problem with autoneg, however unlikely.

Comment: //Either the far port is manually forced to full duplex// Do you mean Autonegotiation + explicit Full Duplex is a violation of configuration? If Yes,Then that seems to be the culprit because our current port configuration is as mentioned below.
Type (Non SFP):        10/100/1000BaseT

  Speed:                 10,100,1000,auto

  Duplex:                full

  Trunk encap. type:     802.1Q

  Channel:               yes

  Broadcast suppression: no

  Flowcontrol:           rx-(off/on),tx-(off/on)


And Yes, The Duplex is set as FULL? Is that the smoking gun?

Comment: Autonegotiation means *no manual configuration* (at all) - explicit full duplex deactivates autoneg. With the other side set to autoneg (falling back to half duplex), that's your problem. Set duplex to *auto* and it'll work. If one port is manually configured on one side *the other side must be configured in the exact same way*. Furthermore, *autonegotiation is mandatory for GbE* - a manual config may cause the port to fall back to 100/10.

Comment: Excellent Master. This is the sole reason I love this Stack Exchange. You are the best.

Comment: Is there any source of documentation I can refer here? I'm sure that is the next question our DC guys are gonna ask.

Comment: You should check your hardware manuals, they should state that GbE requires autoneg and what happens when it's deactivated. Also, IEEE 802.3 Clause 40.5 clearly says "All 1000BASE-T PHYs shall provide support for Auto-Negotiation (Clause 28) and shall be capable of operating as MASTER or SLAVE." Your DC guys should a) know this and b) help your with your diagnosis.

Comment: The *port operating status* should always show "full duplex" as result of auto negotiation. However, you must not *configure* the port for full duplex (admin status) as that breaks autoneg. In doubt, we'd need to see the switch config for that port.

Comment: Okay,I think I jumped the gun after seeing the configuration as FULL in both Interface status and Port capabilities. It seems like in 5596UP switch family the port status will be shown as full Duplex as you said. I don't think they have explicitly changed the switch configuration. I will ask them to share the running configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Some Cisco Platforms (most access switch types of the Catalyst 2900/3600/3800 series and their older siblings too) support these commands:

```
interface GigabitEthernet M/NN
 ...
 ! select which set of speeds are offered during auto-neg
 speed auto 1000 100 10 
 ...
```

This opens a path to debugging an Autoneg issue between switchport and NIC - by just offering one data rate, you can restrict the autoneg scope and check at which speeds the NIC will autoneg.

However, reading the data sheets of the 5596 (which variety? 5596UP, 5596T?), I think there is no support for 10/100M on any of the  RJ45 ports.

That brings us back to Zac67's answer: probably cabling.

Comment: The Switch model is 5596UP.

Answer (score 1):

1000BaseT uses all 4 pairs in the cable bidirectionally, so a failure in pair 1 or 4 should theoretically affect both switch and host and force a fallback to 100 Mb/s. A failure in pair 2 or 3 would give a 'link down' (you don't actually say the link is up, but I assume so).

So, I would start with the cable (not forgetting to check for bent pins in the connectors).

If this doesn't cure the problem you've probably got a port failure on one side or the other. You could try forcing 100 Mb/s auto-duplex (if possible, if not full-duplex).

Comment: Thanks, We tried to change to 100Base T/FULL and it is working without any issues now. We are only encountering the issue with 1000 Base T/FULL.

Comment: That's another strong pointer to what Zac67 and grahamj42 were hinting at: cabling issue. If it works at 100M, but not at 1000M, very probably not all 4 wire pairs are ok.

Comment: Note that not all devices support a fallback from 1000BASE-T to 100BASE-TX - it's not by IEEE standard but was introduced by Broadcom. For instance, our HP/Aruba switches don't, not even the most recent ones. I'm using a two-pair loopback adapter to quickly test for that. Without the fallback, a two-pair link simply doesn't come up with 1000/100/10 autonegotiation due to PCS pairing failing.